# Unselect selected listbox item after hitting a button?

Tags: c#, winforms

Im struggling with some entity framework stuff.

I have this code :

```
 if (LsbSsd.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            Csharppcbuilder.Artikelen artikel = Database.pe.Artikelen.Where(x => x.Naam == LsbSsd.SelectedItem.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
            databank.DeleteArtikel(artikel);


        }
```

My problem is that everything gets added to the other listbox and it does exactly what i want, but i cant seem to deselect items when i've added them to the other listbox.

What i've tried :

```
 if (LsbSsd.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            Csharppcbuilder.Artikelen artikel = Database.pe.Artikelen.Where(x => x.Naam == LsbSsd.SelectedItem.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
            databank.DeleteArtikel(artikel);
            LsbSsd.SelectedIndex = -1;

        }
```

Hope someone can help me out.

edit : if someone needs more context i can provide it

Comment: Have you tried doing `LsbSsd.SelectedItem = null;` ?

Comment: You would have to post code that duplicates the behavior.  `LsbSsd.SelectedIndex = -1;` should work, and if it doesn't, something else is going on that we can't see.  Check your other events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clear the [`ListBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox(v=vs.110).aspx)'s selection in `WinForms` if this [`LsbSsd.SelectedIndex = -1;`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindex(v=vs.110).aspx) is not working try using [`ClearSelected`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.clearselected(v=vs.110).aspx) method `LsbSsd.ClearSelected();`